# C++ copy vs reference memory efficiency

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, reference, copy

Assumed that we have defined a vector (regardless of size and type of the elements; but `vec.size() >= 1`) and we want to iterate through the entire vector, but do not want to modify any element:

```
std::vector<type> vec = someData;

for (type item : vec) {
   // do something
   // but assumed no manipulation of item
   // I can access item which is a copy of vec[i]
}

for (const type &item : vec) {
   // do something
   // but assumed no manipulation of item
   // I can access item which is a immutable reference to vec[i]
}
```

Both – copy and reference – will create new memory, either with a copy of the value or the address to that value in `vec[i]` (remind: we only want to look at the elements!).

For complex types in `vec` it is definitely more efficient to use a reference, because the size of the reference in the memory is less than the actual element in `vec[i]`.

But what if the elements in `vec` are of type `int` with 4 Bytes width or so? Will the address or the actual `int` contain a bigger size? So rather use a copy or a reference?

(I do not consider to use a reference for types like int or double! … but I am interested, so please make your answers general.)

Thanks :-)

Comment: ***Both – copy and reference – will create new memory, either with a copy of the value or the address to that value in vec[i] (remind: we only want to look at the elements!).*** A reference does not necessarily need any additional storage even for the address.

Comment: a reference is just an alias. It does not necessarily occupy any memory

Comment: Assume that additional memory is used for the address? Will the address be more in size or a simple int value, in average case?

Comment: Or in other words: a reference for the above example is more efficient? For int types too? Even if it does not make a huge difference?

Comment: any selfrespecting compiler will realize that no additional memory is needed for the reference in your code. Don't do premature optimization, look at the assembly

Comment: Even in the copy case, no additional memory might be needed. `item` might be just mapped to a register instead.

Comment: Okay! Thank you guys!

Comment: @lsc May be noteworthy, that the compiler can decide to use the same implementation as for a const reference of a const parameter value.